# Must churchgoers be registered with the government in Kansas City?

Tags: united-states, religion, surveillance

According to [this article](https://lc.org/newsroom/details/20200501churchgoers-must-register-with-the-government-in-kansas-city) and to [this Reddit thread, linking the article in fact](https://www.reddit.com/r/TraditionalCatholics/comments/gcdpqa/churchgoers_must_register_with_the_government_in/):

> Kansas City, Missouri, officials are now requiring every church to submit a list of members and attendees along with their names, addresses and telephone numbers to city officials for *tracking and surveillance purposes*.

Is this true? Is this rule applied to any people gathering?

Comment: A comment on the reddit thread: *That's not entirely correct. They must keep a log so that if someone who attends is infected, they can follow up with others in attendance. There is nothing requiring the churches to submit their logs to the government, though it is implied that it would be necessary if there is an outbreak in the church congregation.*

Comment: @IonicăBizău That's OK. I think it is, and we can disagree.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The mayor's 4th order of 30 April 2020 said, in part:

[image: screencap of mayoral order]

> Religious gatherings, including but not limited to, weddings, funerals, memorial services, and wakes, of ten (10) persons inside or ten (10) percent of building occupancy (whichever number is greater) and fifty (50) people outside may resume, provided social distancing is maintained and event organizers maintain a record of attendees. Data obtained by the Department of Public Health, pursuant to this provision, shall, to the extent allowed by law, remain confidential in accordance with professional public health standards and may be used only to address public health concerns.

But now (4 May 2020) it has been superseded and the record of attendees in now only recommended.  It is optional now.

Comment: This answer is incomplete.  What does the mayor's order say about those gatherings?  What data are obtained, by whom, and under what circumstances are they shared?  The reddit comment I quoted claims data are only provided if there is a confirmed covid-19 case.  And can you please transcribe the text for accessibility reasons?

Comment: @gerrit I linked to the full order and transcribed the selection.

Comment: Sorry, commenters, [but we don't care about your political opinions](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3858/sorry-but-we-dont-care-about-your-political-opinions).